# window.open() Second time refresh (Don't open another window)

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

1. Click Link (ex: onclick="javascript:window.open().location.href='URL')
2. Open New Window(or New tab)

First time only open new window(tab) but Second time refresh same window.(Don't open another window)

How can this be possible?

(Problem solved)

```
    function newWindow(url,target)
    {
        if(localStorage.getItem(target))
        {
            window.open(url,target);
        }else
        {
            localStorage.setItem(target,true);
            window.open(url,target);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` to solve this problem:

```
localStorage.setItem("secondWindow", true)
```

Then create a function for `onclick` that checks if the value exist by doing `localStorage.getItem("secondWindow");`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can assume it would be possible would be with a cookie, just save a cookie on the users browser that a window was open. Check for cookie, if it doesn't appear, open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

   <script>
       function myFunction() {
           var url = "https://www.google.com";
           var target = "blank"
        if(localStorage.getItem(target))
         {
           window.open(url,target);
         }
         else
           {
             localStorage.setItem(target,true);
             window.open(url,target);
           }
         }
     </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, please add some references and/or explanation of why/how this code works!